# Shiny Dashboard search bar display

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I am currently using R shinydashboard, and I have a problem with the way the search bar is displayed. Is there any way to solve this? I tried to add shinydashboard:: even though it should not be needed, but it makes no difference. It's a bit of a silly question but the appearance is really bugging me.

Using the sidebarSearchForm function, the search bar should look like this

[image: shinydashboard default searchbar]

But instead it comes out like this:

[image: my output]

It's not a huge problem, but I am curious about what causes this (it appears both in the window application and browser).

```
dashboardSidebar(

    sidebarMenu(
      sidebarSearchForm(textId = "searchbar", buttonId = "searchbtn", label = "Search..."),
      menuItem("Current state", tabName="state", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Stats", tabName="stats", icon = icon("bar-chart")),
      menuItem("Help", tabName="help", icon = icon("question-circle"))
    )
),
```

Comment: You can style it however you want with CSS.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I used the sidebarSearchForm function which normally should not require any other styling, but unfortunately it displays that gap between the input field and the button and I don't really understand why is this happening.

Comment: What do you want to change about the display of the search bar?

Comment: Could you also post a minimum working example?

Comment: @jordan thanks for replying. I uploaded a picture of how the search bar should look like by default vs how it looks like in my case. It's a minor thing but I am a bit puzzled of why this appears. I searched alot of dashboards implementations and the code is exactly the same, still in my case it appears with a small gap.

Comment: @IanWesley I updated the description of the issue.

Comment: @cartita what browser are you using to view the search bar?
Try using a different browser (Edge, Firefox, Chrome) and see if you get the same results.

Comment: @jordan Chrome67

Comment: @jordan I tried now, it gives me the same result.

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED

I added a separate CSS file and I set the border of the main search box container to none and the margins of the button (magnifying glass) to 0. Thanks to everybody for the help!

Comment: I'm a bit late, but could you share the CSS code you used to do that ?